# use both cyclic and b-spline smoothers in statsmodels.gam

Tags: python, statsmodels, gam

I am attempting to run a Generalized Additive Model using Python's statsmodels library. I'm more familiar with R's mgcv library, which allows any reasonable combination of b-spline, cyclic, etc. smoothers in the same model specification. statsmodels's GAM implementation allows for the use of b-spline or cyclic smoothers via the `BSplines` and `CyclicCubicSplines` functions, respectively, but there doesn't seem to be a way to use both of these simultaneously. This seems like a strange limitation, since I can imagine many scenarios where a model might have a cyclic predictor (week of year, for example) alongside other non-cyclic smoothed predictors.

The following code snippet demonstrates that you can use either/or, but my (admitted naive) attempt to combine them fails. Is there a way to do this, or is it simply not possible with statsmodels's GAM implementation?

```
from statsmodels.gam.api import GLMGam, BSplines, CyclicCubicSplines
from statsmodels.gam.tests.test_penalized import df_autos

# specify weight and hp as smoothed terms
bs_spline = BSplines(df_autos[['weight', 'hp']], df=[3, 3], degree=[2, 2])

# run the model with the smooth terms above, plus fuel and drive as linear terms
gam_bs = GLMGam.from_formula('city_mpg ~ fuel + drive', data=df_autos, smoother=bs_spline)
res_bs = gam_bs.fit()
print(res_bs.summary())

# specify bs as cyclic (obviously a slightly worse fit, but it runs)
bs_cyclic = CyclicCubicSplines(df_autos[['weight', 'hp']], df=[3, 3])
gam_cyclic = GLMGam.from_formula('city_mpg ~ fuel + drive', data=df_autos, smoother=bs_cyclic)
res_cyclic = gam_cyclic.fit()
print(res_cyclic.summary())

# attempt to combine B-spline (weight) and cyclic (hp) smooths
bs_combined = [
    BSplines(df_autos[['weight']], df=[3], degree=[2]),
    CyclicCubicSplines(df_autos[['hp']], df=[3])
]
gam_combined = GLMGam.from_formula('city_mpg ~ fuel + drive', data=df_autos, smoother=bs_combined) # fails here
```